# Ethereum: Parse timestamp from signature

Tags: typescript, ethereum, solidity, digital-signature, ecdsa

I have a simple function which allows used to sign a message:

```
const originalMessage = "I agree to the terms and conditions of this site.";
const timestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 3600; 
const messageWithTimestamp = `${originalMessage}\n Timestamp: ${timestamp}`;
const signer = provider.getSigner();
const signature = await signer.signMessage(messageWithTimestamp);
```

I'd like to verify that the signature was withing x minutes o

```
function verify(address signer, uint256 timestamp, bytes memory signature, bytes32 sigR, bytes32 sigS, uint8 sigV) public view returns (bool) {
    require(block.timestamp < (timestamp + 3600))
    return signer == ecrecover(signature, sigV, sigR, sigS);
}
```

The issue is that method is clearly vulnerable, and I need to verify that the timestamp send to the verify method was the same timestamp that exists in the signature.

How can I parse the timestamp from the signature?

**Note:** The message format is not that important to me,  however I would like the parse to be semi deterministic, e.g it parses the message via a key, or there is a block of data that can be pulled with a variable amount of bytes which are appended at the end